# android, layout issue, 480x854

Tags: android, layout, text, checkbox

I have Checkbox and I setted paddingLeft="150dp" for a text, when I use phone with resolution 480x854 for example neo v, the checkbox is over text. layout it's fine for other resolutions.

In res I have only "layout".
What is wrong? Why only for 480x854

Comment: A: Please provide an example of the code in question.

B: What other resolutions have you been trying?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use dp to position your views, as you are bound to have problems when switching devices. Instead use a RelativeLayout and its attributes, like android:layout_toLeftOf, android:layout_centerHorizontal and so on.

You can read more about RelativeLayouts here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html

Comment: I mostly agree with @DanielS here, although I created an app with several images, evenly spaced apart, etc. I captured screen resolution and passed through a math formula I set up that determined my `Margins`.

Comment: But I'm using label for the checkbox

Comment: DIP is useful for sizing, mainly useless for positioning unless you do your own calculations as Asok says.